# d3 - table, each char in the display string end up in a separate "td"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building a single column table. Code is as:

```
var report = [ Jan 2016, report1, March2016, report2, June 2017, report3 ];

var rtable = d3.select('body')
.append('table');

var trows = rtable.selectAll('tr')
.data(report)
.enter()
.append('tr');

var tcell = trows.selectAll('td')
.data( function(row) {  
return row;       // ToDo - more data manipulation
})
.enter()
.append('td')
.html( function(d) {
 return d;
 });
```

[image: this is how the output looks]

My question is: instead of having each character in a separate "td", I like the whole string to be in one "td".

Some thing similar to what this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/ma7Dn/) does.

when I use d.join as

```
.html( function(d) {
 return d.join(", ");
 });
```

I get a "Uncaught TypeError: d.join is not a function"

what am I missing, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to nest your data join to get the effect that you want. Instead, you can just append a `td` to the `tr` of your first data join.

```
var report = [ "Jan 2016", "report1", "March2016", "report2", "June 2017", "report3" ];

var rtable = d3.select('body')
    .append('table');

var trows = rtable.selectAll('tr')
    .data(report)
    .enter()
    .append('tr')
    .append('td') // new code here
    .html((d) => d);
```

When you do `function(d) {return d}` or `(d) => d` inside `.html()`, this will now return the entire string, as opposed to each character.

As for why `.join()` doesn't work - String doesn't have that method. The example you linked uses a nested array. During that data join, each data point is an array, which will have the `.join()` method.

Comment: @laks: Glad to hear so! Please mark this as the accepted answer for others who will view this question.